# Java exceptions, after catch it stills prints whats after

Tags: java, exception

I am using some exceptions, but even if one is thrown and catched, it does continue output whats after the catch block.

I want my exception that is thrown, to get catched and only print out whats in the catch body, unless there is no exception and move on to the last souf.

Somehow though, when i have an exception, my catch body is printed but also the souf after it, that should not be printed.

How do i organize these exceptions?

------- a method that throws an exception

```
   public double getHeight() throws ExceptionCheck {
        //if end point is not set, return -1 (error)
        if(points[1] == null){
            throw new ExceptionCheck("The height cannot be calculated, the end point is missing!\n\n");
        } else {
            double height = points[1].getY() - points[0].getY();
            return height;
        }
    }
```

------- the method that handles the throw from getHeight

```
@Override
public double getArea() {
    //if end point is not set, return -1 (error)

    double area = 0;

    try {
        area = getHeight() * getWidth();
    }
    catch(ExceptionCheck e){
        System.out.printf("The area cannot be calculated, the end point is missing!\n\n");
    }

    return area;
}
```

---------- here the last SOUF after the catch should not be printed, but gets printed anyways

```
private static void printArea(Shape shape) {
    System.out.println("Printing area of a " + shape.getClass().getSimpleName());

    double area = 0d;
    // Get area of the shape and print it.
    try {
        area = shape.getArea();
    }
    catch(ExceptionCheck e){
        System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
    }
   System.out.println("The area is: " + area);
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking about, You should make your post short and straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how `catch` works. If that shouldn't be printed when there is an exception, you **must** move it into the body of the `try`. Like,

```
// Get area of the shape and print it.
try {
    double area = shape.getArea();
    System.out.println("The area is: " + area); // <-- if the previous line throws
                                                // an exception, this will not print.
}
catch(ExceptionCheck e){
    System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
}
```

Your method `getArea` doesn't actually `throw` the `Exception`. It prints and swallows it. For the above `catch` to be invoked, you would also have to modify `getArea` like

```
@Override
public double getArea() throws ExceptionCheck {
    try {
        return getHeight() * getWidth();
    }
    catch(ExceptionCheck e){
        System.out.printf("The area cannot be calculated, the end point is missing!\n\n");
        throw e; // <-- add this.
    }
}
```

Comment: It still does, have tried that also. Can it be something wrong in my getArea()? Should the "return" also be in the try? And if so, how? Because the method will still require a return outside of the try bracets.

Comment: @Thesar Yes. Your `getArea` doesn't ever throw an exception. It silently swallows them instead.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, except for that both throws are geting printed. The print of 
 getArea() "The area cannot..."  and the print of getHeight() "The height cannot..."

Comment: Solved it by only having throw new ExceptionCheck("The area cannot...") in the catch body in getArea(). Thanks Elliott!